# iOS 7, corrupt UINavigationBar when swiping back fast using the default interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an issue that I'm stuck on, but I have no idea why it even happens; If I push a detail controller on the stack, and I swipe back very quickly using the default left edge `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, my parent/root view controller's `UINavigationBar` looks corrupt or something, almost like the built in iOS transition mechanism didn't have time to do it's job at resetting it after the detail view is gone. Also to clarify, everything in this 'corrupt' `UINavigationBar` is still touchable and everything on my parent/root view controller works perfectly.

Is there anyway to reset this `UINavigationBar` to what it should be when the parent/root view controller's viewDidAppear method gets called?

Note that this bug does not occur if I tap the top left back button instead of using the left edge `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`.

Edit: I added an NSLog to check the navigationBar's subview count on viewDidAppear on the parent/root view controller, and the count is always the same, corrupt or not, so I'd like to know why the popped controller is wreaking havoc with my `UINavigationBar`.

If you can help me at all, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you.

I've attached a screenshot of what it looks like: Note that the back chevron isn't part of my parent/root view controller, it's part of what was popped off the stack. Testing123 is the title for the parent/root view controller and not that of what was popped off the stack. The head and gear icons are part of the parent/root view controller.

Edit: I've thought something like this could fix the issue, but turns out it doesn't, and is really bad experience IMO too. This is not the kind of solution I'm looking for. I'm posting a large bounty so this can be resolved correctly! . I just can't have this weird UI behavior be in a production quality app.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in the simulator and/or actual device? If device, what kind of device are you using?

Comment: Happens on both simulator and on any iOS device, and any iOS version greater than 7.0

Comment: It looks like you have a custom back button on your view controller. Did you follow the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817453/ios-7-uinavigationbar-has-hidden-back-button?rq=1

Comment: No, I don't have any custom back button at all...

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you are pushing a detail controller on, and I see a face icon on the left side of the navigation bar, which is where the back button should be. Can you post photos of the two view controllers (master / detail) so that we know what the VCs should look like?

Comment: Those are my left and right bar button items on the parent/root view.

Comment: I said the screenshot is what it looks like after i get back to the parent controller from the detail.

Comment: It is weird, can you post any code or a sample project that illustrates this, as I can't seem to replicate the behavior at all.

Comment: Updated my question which contains 2 links, 1 showing a video, and the other the barebones project.

Comment: yeah, just tested your code and see the issue you are describing. I tried pushing the second vc via a segue to see if that would help, but you can still get the issue via that method as well. The code being as bare bones as it is, its probably an error with the UINavigationController. I am not sure why I can't replicate it within my own app or any app I've downloaded. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Can you please upload your code to GitHub? We have DropBox blocked here in work. Thx

Comment: Hey Leo, here is the link: https://github.com/troop231/testing123

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I ran it in the simulator and seems to work as expected.

Comment: Did you not watch the screenshot video? I can replicate the issue all the time. I know dropbox is blocked, so maybe I can upload video elsewhere.

Comment: http://youtu.be/gHGsFV6Th6Y

Comment: @troop231 Although I can reproduce the problem in the Simulator, it works as expected (it didn't happen even once) in my device (iPhone5 latest iOS7). Can you share a little info about the device you have tested this? **Edit:** Also happening on stock apps in Simulator (try Settings) so it's definitely a system bug...

Comment: Yes, I see that now that it is in the Settings app as well. However, surely there is a way to combat this bug and fix it.

Comment: This looks like a simulator bug. What matters is how it looks on device.

Comment: Nope, happens on devices as well

Comment: Can't get it to happen on either an iPhone 4 or 5S with iOS 7. You sure it happens on the device??

Comment: @DylanGattey Yes I'm sure.. otherwise I wouldn't have posted question

Comment: No one else can get it to appear on any device but you. Probably not a problem that anyone will notice. What kind of device do you have? Jailbroken? iOS 8? Anything weird about it?

Comment: No. iOS 7, iPhone 5. And yes it is a random problem and needs fixed.

Comment: Note that you are getting downvotes only because of [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261431/source-code-on-github-failed-review/261440?noredirect=1#comment47519_261440).

Comment: @troop231 - Instead of getting upset, why not post excerpts from your `AppDelegate.m`, `ViewController.m`, and `ViewController2.m` to show that there's nothing special going on? I believe that satisfies the site rules with respect to including relevant source code in your question. Also, the full blown Xcode project includes a lot of irrelevant fodder. There's probably no need for the Test component, Help component, and Localization components, and its likely one of the reasons the site requires a minimal example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### TL;DR

I made a category on `UIViewController` that hopefully fixes this issue for you. I can't actually reproduce the navigation bar corruption on a device, but I can do it on the simulator pretty frequently, and this category solves the problem for me. Hopefully it also solves it for you on the device.

### The Problem, and the Solution

I actually don't know exactly what causes this, but the navigation bar's subviews' layers' animations seem to either be executing twice or not fully completing or... something. Anyway, I found that you can simply add some animations to these subviews in order to force them back to where they should be (with the right opacity, color, etc). The trick is to use your view controller's `transitionCoordinator` object and hook into a couple of events – namely the event that happens when you lift your finger up and the interactive pop gesture recognizer finishes and the rest of the animation starts, and then the event that occurs when the non-interactive half of the animation finishes.

You can hook into these events using a couple methods on the `transitionCoordinator`, specifically `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:` and `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:`. In the former, we create copies of all of the current animations of the navbar's subviews' layers, modify them slightly, and save them so we can apply them later when the non-interactive portion of the animation finishes, which is in the completion block of the latter of those two methods.

### Summary

1. Listen for when the interactive portion of the transition ends
2. Gather up the animations for all the views' layers in the navigation bar
3. Copy and modify these animations slightly (set fromValue to the same thing as the toValue, set duration to zero, and a few other things)
4. Listen for when the non-interactive portion of the transition ends
5. Apply the copied/modified animations back to the views' layers

### Code

And here's the code for the `UIViewController` category:

```
@interface UIViewController (FixNavigationBarCorruption)

- (void)fixNavigationBarCorruption;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (FixNavigationBarCorruption)

/**
 * Fixes a problem where the navigation bar sometimes becomes corrupt
 * when transitioning using an interactive transition.
 *
 * Call this method in your view controller's viewWillAppear: method
 */
- (void)fixNavigationBarCorruption
{
    // Get our transition coordinator
    id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator;

    // If we have a transition coordinator and it was initially interactive when it started,
    // we can attempt to fix the issue with the nav bar corruption.
    if ([coordinator initiallyInteractive]) {

        // Use a map table so we can map from each view to its animations
        NSMapTable *mapTable = [[NSMapTable alloc] initWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory
                                                         valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory
                                                             capacity:0];

        // This gets run when your finger lifts up while dragging with the interactivePopGestureRecognizer
        [coordinator notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

            // Loop through our nav controller's nav bar's subviews
            for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {

                NSArray *animationKeys = view.layer.animationKeys;
                NSMutableArray *anims = [NSMutableArray array];

                // Gather this view's animations
                for (NSString *animationKey in animationKeys) {
                    CABasicAnimation *anim = (id)[view.layer animationForKey:animationKey];

                    // In case any other kind of animation somehow gets added to this view, don't bother with it
                    if ([anim isKindOfClass:[CABasicAnimation class]]) {

                        // Make a pseudo-hard copy of each animation.
                        // We have to make a copy because we cannot modify an existing animation.
                        CABasicAnimation *animCopy = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:anim.keyPath];

                        // CABasicAnimation properties
                        // Make sure fromValue and toValue are the same, and that they are equal to the layer's final resting value
                        animCopy.fromValue = [view.layer valueForKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
                        animCopy.toValue = [view.layer valueForKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
                        animCopy.byValue = anim.byValue;

                        // CAPropertyAnimation properties
                        animCopy.additive = anim.additive;
                        animCopy.cumulative = anim.cumulative;
                        animCopy.valueFunction = anim.valueFunction;

                        // CAAnimation properties
                        animCopy.timingFunction = anim.timingFunction;
                        animCopy.delegate = anim.delegate;
                        animCopy.removedOnCompletion = anim.removedOnCompletion;

                        // CAMediaTiming properties
                        animCopy.speed = anim.speed;
                        animCopy.repeatCount = anim.repeatCount;
                        animCopy.repeatDuration = anim.repeatDuration;
                        animCopy.autoreverses = anim.autoreverses;
                        animCopy.fillMode = anim.fillMode;

                        // We want our new animations to be instantaneous, so set the duration to zero.
                        // Also set both the begin time and time offset to 0.
                        animCopy.duration = 0;
                        animCopy.beginTime = 0;
                        animCopy.timeOffset = 0;

                        [anims addObject:animCopy];
                    }
                }

                // Associate the gathered animations with each respective view
                [mapTable setObject:anims forKey:view];
            }
        }];

        // The completion block here gets run after the view controller transition animation completes (or fails)
        [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

            // Iterate over the mapTable's keys (views)
            for (UIView *view in mapTable.keyEnumerator) {

                // Get the modified animations for this view that we made when the interactive portion of the transition finished
                NSArray *anims = [mapTable objectForKey:view];

                // ... and add them back to the view's layer
                for (CABasicAnimation *anim in anims) {
                    [view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:anim.keyPath];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

And then just call this method in your view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method (in your test project's case, it would be the `ViewController` class):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self fixNavigationBarCorruption];
}
```

Comment: Good solution. I think this works. But why don't your try to customise the UINavigationControllerDelegate with a different animation? I have been trying to do that in the last 2 days but couldn't produce a good result.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks Ricky, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.

Comment: You may check the sample project on that https://github.com/objcio/issue5-view-controller-transitions I believe the issue of this question is related to the animation. The problem could be solved by changing the **fromViewController.view.transform**. I am not entirely sure as I am still new in learning the transition between different viewcontrollers.

Comment: @Ricky But @troop231 is not doing any kind of custom transition. It's just a standard navigation controller pop, using the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` that was introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: I understand that. I believe a custom transition that mimics the standard pop transition with a slight change of code might solve the problem. I could be wrong as I do not have too much knowledge in this area. I am still learning.

Comment: @Ricky Oh! I see. Yes, that would probably solve the problem, but then you have to try to mimic the standard pop transition. When you do that, you run the risk of Apple one day changing how that animation looks, and suddenly your mimic animation looks nothing like the standard animation, and you have to go in and redo it all.

Comment: Congratulations, looks like you nailed it! :) Copying and reapplying layer animations was a really smart approach.

Comment: Exactly the answer worthy of a large bounty, this appears to have solved my problem! Thank you so much 

Answer (score 3):

After investigating this issue for some time with debug console, Instruments and Reveal, I have found out the following:

1) On simulator the bug can be recreated every time, if using Profile/Automation Template and adding the following script:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var appWindow = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
appWindow.buttons()[0].tap();
target.delay(1);
target.flickFromTo({x:2, y: 100}, {x:160, y: 100});
```

2) On real device (iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1) this script never causes the bug. I tried various options for flick coordinates and the delay.

3) UINavigationBar consists of:

```
_UINavigationBarBackground (doesn't seem to be related to the bug)
      _UIBackdropView
           _UIBackgropEffectView
           UIView
      UIImageView
UINavigationItemView
      UILabel (visible in the bug)
_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView (visible in the bug)
```

4) When bug happens UILabel looks half transparent and in the wrong position, but the actual properties of the UILabel are correct (alpha: 1 and frame as in normal situation). Also _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView looks doesn't correspond to actual properties - it is visible although it's alpha is 0.

From this I conclude that it's a bug of Simulator and that you can't even detect from the code that something is wrong.

So @troop231 - are you 100% sure this also happens on device?

Comment: Yes I'm sure.. otherwise I wouldn't have posted question

Comment: In that case looks like the bug is not in UIKit level, but deeper -perhaps Core Animation or Core Graphics.

Comment: Is there anyway to get at the CALayers and fix them?

Comment: I'm checking that, but so far the only thing that fixes is the back button (it hides). The title stays as is, if you force redraw the layer or even change the font size.

Comment: Regarding number 2, I also can confirm that this issue occurs on a real device, iPhone 5S, iOS 7.0.6.

Comment: I upvote for the interface layers for UINavigationBar. Unrelated question: Andris, how can you actually find the interface layers? Any official documentation on that.

Comment: @Ricky You can see a lot just via Debugger console for ex. "po [[self.navigationController navigationBar] subviews]" for some properties you need to use "valueForKey:" for them to work. Also you can use Reveal.

Answer (score 0):

## Key Concept

Disable gesture recognizer when pushing view controller, and enable it when view appeared.

## A Common Solution: Subclassing

You can subclass `UINavigationController` and `UIViewController` to prevent corruption.

#### MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; // disable
}
```

#### MyViewController : UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES; // enable
}
```

## Problem: Too annoying

- Need to use `MyNavigationController` and `MyViewController` instead of `UINavigationController` and `UIViewController`.
- Need to subclass for `UITableViewController`, `UICollectionViewController`, and more.

## A Better Solution: Method Swizzling

It could be done by swizzling `UINavigationController` and `UIViewController` methods. Want to know about method swizzling, visit [here](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).

Example below uses [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) that makes method swizzling easy.

#### UINavigationController

```
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewDidLoad)
                    withMethod:@selector(hack_viewDidLoad)
                         error:nil];
        [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)
                    withMethod:@selector(hack_pushViewController:animated:)
                         error:nil];
    });
}

- (void)hack_viewDidLoad
{
    [self hack_viewDidLoad];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
}

- (void)hack_pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self hack_pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

#### UIViewController

```
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewDidAppear:)
                    withMethod:@selector(hack_viewDidAppear:)
                         error:nil];
    });
}

- (void)hack_viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self hack_viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

## Being Simple: Use Open Source

### SwipeBack

**[SwipeBack](https://github.com/devxoul/SwipeBack)** does it automatically without any code.

With [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org), just add a line below into your `Podfile`. You don't need to write any code. CocoaPods automatically import SwipeBack globally.

`pod 'SwipeBack'`

Install pod, and it's done!

Comment: @EmrahAkgül, could you please make an issue on GitHub with your test environment? (iOS version, SwipeBack version, etc.)